# BOT Telegram in Python run in IDLE but won't runs in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-idle

I made a simple program in python to send a message in a group on telegram. The program works normally in IDLE (Jupyter/Spyder), however the program.py doesn't work when run directly by python.exe

```
import telegram

TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = '5xxxxxxxxx:AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXM'
TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID = '-7XXXXXXXX'


bot = telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)

bot.send_message(chat_id=TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID, text=" Test ")
```

ps: The others programs (other libraries) works normally. When running this program no error appears, but it opens the terminal and nothing appears

Comment: Nothing appears? What should appear? You do not print anything.

Comment: @KlausD.  It was supposed to send a message on telegram, but it doesn't. If I copy the script and paste it into the console the program works. If I add print (" 123 Test") before  import telegram line it appears, but if I put this line after the import telegram nothing appears.